Use python 3.x task failing on linux self hosted agent
I have been trying to get a private agent to work with Azure pipelines for a few days now. It was straight forward enough to install the agent itself on an Azure hosted linux VM and connect it to devops so that i could send jobs to it. The problems come from trying to install python on the agent.
I have created the directory structure as recommended here "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/use-python-version-v0?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops#how-can-i-configure-a-self-hosted-agent-to-use-this-task" and pipeline is able to find the tool under while using Use Python task under pipeline but on the next step during install requirements its again going to local system python and referring that.
Found tool in cache: Python 3.10.14 x64 
Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: myagent/_work/_tool/Python/3.10.14/x64

Use Python Version Image
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/<Username>/myagent/_work/_temp/a2f27dba-44e5-471b-8de5-fe3148e7d196.sh
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /home/<Username>/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (24.2)
Collecting azure-functions (from -r ./requirements.txt (line 5))

Install requirements still referring base system python
Do we have install the python inside the _tool directory even post keeping the files from this location. "github.com/actions/python-versions/releases"
I checked by going inside the _tool location and it still does not resolve the python version when we go inside Python 3.10.14. May I  please know what I am missing from the documentation or what changes are required to make pipeline to use the version specified.


stages:
- stage: BuildDev
  displayName: Build (DEV)

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build (DEV)
    pool:
      name: $(vmImageNameDev)
      demands:
      - agent.os -equals Linux


    steps:

    - checkout: Platform_Branch
    
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Use Python 3.10'
      inputs:
         versionSpec: '3.10'
         disableDownloadFromRegistry: true
    
    - script: |
         python -m pip install --upgrade pip
         pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
      workingDirectory: $(workingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Install requirements'
    
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: $(workingDirectory)
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: 'zip'
        archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish files as drop'
      inputs: 
        pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        artifactName: 'drop'

- stage: DeployToDev
  displayName: Deploy stage (DEV)
  dependsOn: BuildDev
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployToDev
    displayName: Deploy to Dev
    environment: 'DEV'
    pool:
      name: $(vmImageNameDev)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:

          steps:
          - download: current
            artifact: drop

          - task: AzureFunctionApp@2
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              connectedServiceNameARM: '$(serviceConnectionDev)'
              appType: 'functionAppLinux'
              appName: '$(functionAppNameDev)'
              deployToSlotOrASE: true
              resourceGroupName: 'RG_NAME'
              runtimeStack: 'PYTHON|3.10'
              slotName: 'production'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              appSettings: -RequestTimeout 5000





[devopsadmin@ops-ls-01 sourcetool]$ ./setup.sh
Check if Python hostedtoolcache folder exist...
Deleting Python 3.10.14
Create Python 3.10.14 folder
Copy Python binaries to hostedtoolcache folder
Create additional symlinks (Required for the UsePythonVersion Azure Pipelines task and the setup-pytho                                                       n GitHub Action)
Upgrading pip...
./python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.10.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file:                                                        No such file or directory
[devopsadmin@ops-ls-d01 sourcetool]$ sudo ln -s ~/myagent/_work/_tool/Python/3.10.14/x64/lib/li                                                       bpython3.10.so.1.0 /usr/lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0
[devopsadmin@ops-ls-d01 sourcetool]$ ./setup.sh
Check if Python hostedtoolcache folder exist...
Deleting Python 3.10.14
Create Python 3.10.14 folder
Copy Python binaries to hostedtoolcache folder
Create additional symlinks (Required for the UsePythonVersion Azure Pipelines task and the setup-pytho                                                       n GitHub Action)
Upgrading pip...
./python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.10.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file:                                                        No such file or directory
[devopsadmin@ops-ls-d01 sourcetool]$ sudo ln -s ~/myagent/_work/_tool/Python/3.10.14/x64/lib/li                                                       bpython3.10.so.1.0 /usr/lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0': File exists





[devopsadmin@ops-ls-d01 sourcetool]$ ./setup.sh
Check if Python hostedtoolcache folder exist...
Deleting Python 3.10.14
Create Python 3.10.14 folder
Copy Python binaries to hostedtoolcache folder
Create additional symlinks (Required for the UsePythonVersion Azure Pipelines task and the setup-python GitHub Action)
Upgrading pip...
./python: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /home/<username>/myagent/_work/_tool/Python/3.10.14/x64/lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0)
./python: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.35' not found (required by /home/<username>/myagent/_work/_tool/Python/3.10.14/x64/lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0)
./python: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /home/<username>/myagent/_work/_tool/Python/3.10.14/x64/lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0)





[devopsadmin@-ops-ls-d01 sourcetool]$ sudo ln -sf ~/myagent/_work/_tool/Python/3.10.14/x64/lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0 /usr/lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0
[devopsadmin@ops-ls-d01 sourcetool]$ ./setup.sh
Check if Python hostedtoolcache folder exist...
Deleting Python 3.10.14
Create Python 3.10.14 folder
Copy Python binaries to hostedtoolcache folder
Create additional symlinks (Required for the UsePythonVersion Azure Pipelines task and the setup-python GitHub Action)
Upgrading pip...
./python: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /home/devopsadmin/myagent/_work/_tool/Python/3.10.14/x64/lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0)
./python: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.35' not found (required by /home/devopsadmin/myagent/_work/_tool/Python/3.10.14/x64/lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0)
./python: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /home/devopsadmin/myagent/_work/_tool/Python/3.10.14/x64/lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0)




Can you share more details about your pipeline definition?

Hi Kevin Lu-MSFT, I have attached the pipeline definition.

I have checked the Pipeline definition. Can you try to use the commnad:  python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip to replace the commd:python -m pip install --upgrade pip to force the python to use the correct version?

Hi, ran it but since 3.10 is not installed on the base machine and it does not recognize the 3.10 version. Do we have to install each version of python by unzipping the files and run ./configure inside the _tool directory. ERROR during previous run.                                                                                           /bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home//myagent/_work/_temp/8f2f5b64-875e-407c-b41d-bd71da2daeb7.sh
python3.10: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.10.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The cause of the issue can be that you are not configure the Python 3.10.14 correctly. After downloading the package from the github, you need to run the setup.sh file to configure the environment. Then it can work. For more detailed info, you can refer to my answer.


I checked by going inside the _tool location and it still does not resolve the python version when we go inside Python 3.10.14.

The cause of the issue can be that you are not configure the Python 3.10.14 correctly. In this case, it will not use the 3.10.14 in the next tasks.
When you download the Python package in the Github: Python Version Release, it contains a file name: setup.sh.
After you unzip the package, you need to run the setup.sh file to configure the environment.
./setup.sh

Here are the steps:
Step1: Download the python package(tar.gz file ) to a temp folder (Not use _tool Folder).
Step2: Run the command to unzip the package.
tar xC tempfplder/  -f  tempfolder/python-3.11.0-linux-22.04-x64.tar.gz

Step3: Run the ./setup.sh to configure the environment. It will automatically create the Python folder and all related files under the _tool folder.
File content:
$AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY/
    Python/
        3.11.4/
            x64/
                bin
                share
                lib
                include
                python
                ....
            x64.complete

When you running the setup.sh file, it may show the following error:

./python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.10.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

To solve this issue, you can link it manually via command:
sudo ln -s ~/youragent/_work/_tool/Python/3.10.14/x64/lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0 /usr/lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0

Then you can use the UsePythonVersion task to set the Python Version.
Update:
Here is my test sample: Install python 3.11.0 on my ubuntu 20.04 machine. Package Name: python-3.11.0-linux-20.04-x64.tar.gz

After running setup.sh file, it will add the required files to the _tool folder and add x64.complete file.
Then when using Use Python task, it will point to the correct version and use it in the next tasks.
For example:


Hi Kevin Lu-MSFT, may i please know which files to be downloaded from here "https://github.com/actions/python-versions/releases?page=3" for RHEL 9.4 version. All this time, I was downloading "python-3.10.14-linux-20.04-x64.tar.gz" file not sure if I am doing the right thing by referring the Ubuntu files. Just an FYI, I am using Linux (rhel 9.4) on my machine.

I am still getting the same issue though symlink  has been added and it prompts me file exists. So, it still keep giving me the same error message during the pipeline run as well "python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.10.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

@Lbits You can run the command: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:unzippedpythonpackagepath/lib to set the shared libraries.

Thanks Kevin Lu-MSFT and may i please know which file do we have to download and unzip  out of these files present here for RHEL 9 - "https://github.com/actions/python-versions/releases?page=3". I hope it wont cause an issue if I use these Ubuntu versions files or can you redirect me to the source files for RHEL 9 version.

@Lbits We need to configure the python environment completely. Then we can use the Use Python Version task to point to the correct python version.

RHEL 9.4 includes GLIBC 2.34 for some reason, and Python binary seems to require GLIBC versions that are not present in RHEL 9.4. Did you come across this sort of an issue while replicating it in your envt  for RHEL 9 ?

Upgrading pip...
./python: /lib64/libm.so.6: version GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /home/devopsadmin/myagent/_work/_tool/Python/3.10.14/x64/lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0) ./python: /lib64/libm.so.6: version GLIBC_2.35' not found (required by /home/devopsadmin/myagent/_work/_tool/Python/3.10.14/x64/lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0)

@Lbits Oh. Yes. I get the same error after running the export command to set the shared libraries. But if I run the sudo ln -s command successfully, it will not show this error.  Maybe you can try to run the command: sudo apt install libc6 to install the required GLIBC.

Or you can run sudo ln -sf to overwrite the existing link.

Ran the above command which was able to overwrite the symlink but getting the exact same issue still - version GLIBC_2.38' not found and version GLIBC_2.35' not found and  ldd --version = ldd (GNU libc) 2.34 and sudo dnf install glibc = Package glibc-2.34-100.el9_4.2.x86_64 is already installed

[ipldevopsadmin@ipl-ops-ls-d01 sourcetool]$ sudo ./setup.sh
Check if Python hostedtoolcache folder exist...
Deleting Python 3.10.14
Create Python 3.10.14 folder
Copy Python binaries to hostedtoolcache folder
Upgrading pip...
./python: /lib64/libm.so.6: version GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0) ./python: /lib64/libm.so.6: version GLIBC_2.35' not found (required by /lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0)
./python: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.38' not found (required by /lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0)

Have you tried to run the command:  sudo apt update  AND sudo apt install libc6 to install GLIBC?

Yes, sudo dnf update and sudo dnf install glibc as apt is not installed.  ldd --version = ldd (GNU libc) 2.34 and sudo dnf install glibc = Package glibc-2.34-100.el9_4.2.x86_64 aleady installed

Tried update and the libc6 install but dint help and still on the same dependency. Shall I try using an Ubuntu machine instead of using RHEL9 ?

After some investigation, the cause of the issue is that the package is installing python3.10 that was compiled/linked against GLIBC-2.25 (or later). This binary can not run on any machine which has older GLIBC. If you need to use the python package in the link above. You may need to change to use suitable linux machine.

You may try to use dnf install python3.10 to install the Python 3.10. Then you can directly use the command: python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip  to use the correct python version

@Lbits Is there any update about this ticket?
